# Annotation with canShowCallout switch viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, annotations, google-api, nsdictionary

I have a problem. I search with google apis to places and let me create a annotation pin on the map. The data is stored in a dict. I try THESE position to transfer with a callout including the data to another ViewController.

Here are Parts of my code:
.h file:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>
#import "MapPoint.h"

#define kGOOGLE_API_KEY @"MyGoogleAPIsKey"
#define kBgQueue dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)



@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate>
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;
    BOOL firstLaunch;
    int currenDist;
}

- (IBAction)myButton:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)myPosition:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end
```

.m file:

```
@implementation FirstViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Make this controller the delegate for the map view.
    self.mapView.delegate = self;

    // Ensure that you can view your own location in the map view.
    [self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];

    //Instantiate a location object.
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    //Make this controller the delegate for the location manager.
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    //Set some parameters for the location object.
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
    firstLaunch=YES;

    [_mapView setCenterCoordinate:_mapView.userLocation.coordinate];

}
-(void)plotPositions:(NSArray *)data {
    // 1 - Remove any existing custom annotations but not the user location blue dot.
    for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in _mapView.annotations)
    {
        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MapPoint class]])
        {
            [_mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }    
    // 2 - Loop through the array of places returned from the Google API.
    for (int i=0; i<[data count]; i++)
    {
        //Retrieve the NSDictionary object in each index of the array.
        NSDictionary* place = [data objectAtIndex:i];
        // 3 - There is a specific NSDictionary object that gives us the location info.
        NSDictionary *geo = [place objectForKey:@"geometry"];
        // Get the lat and long for the location.
        NSDictionary *loc = [geo objectForKey:@"location"];
        // 4 - Get your name and address info for adding to a pin.
        NSString *name = [place objectForKey:@"name"];
        NSString *vicinity = [place objectForKey:@"vicinity"];
        // 4.5 - Get id for detailed view.
        NSString *myId = [place objectForKey:@"id"];
        // Create a special variable to hold this coordinate info.
        CLLocationCoordinate2D placeCoord;
        // Set the lat and long.
        placeCoord.latitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lat"] doubleValue];
        placeCoord.longitude=[[loc objectForKey:@"lng"] doubleValue];

        // 5 - Create a new annotation.
        MapPoint *placeObject = [[MapPoint alloc] initWithName:name address:vicinity coordinate:placeCoord];
        [_mapView addAnnotation:placeObject];

        NSLog(@"%@", myId);
    }

}

-(void)button:(id)sender
{
    //here is my main problem ...
}
```

if i done a misstake or something else tell me that please.
I am grateful for any answer!

okay forget to say I am really new to Obj-C so every tip is usefull for me!

Regards Curtis

Comment: It's not clear exactly what your specific question is.  What's the problem?  If you are getting compiler or run-time errors, please give their exact text.  A couple of things: CLLocationManager is created but startUpdatingLocation is never called; showsUserLocation is set to YES and then in _same_ method you try to retrieve userLocation -- this will usually result in 0,0 coordinates.

Comment: First of all: Thank you for your interest.
My goal is: touch the calloutButton go to a new view and show the data array in that view. 
there is a lot more code in my App and everything is running without erros but there are only missing special methods.

Comment: You should probably split your goal into multiple questions and go one step at a time.  Assuming annotations are showing up, first step is getting a callout button to show in the callout.  That is done by implementing the viewForAnnotation delegate method and setting leftCalloutAccessoryView or rightCalloutAccessoryView.  If you've implemented that delegate method, show that code.  Then, to handle the callout button press, you would implement the calloutAccessoryControlTapped delegate method.  There are many examples in the Apple docs and here that you could search for and start with.

Comment: many thanks. I'm definitely on my project to continue working

Answer (score 0):

As @Anna Karenina said, you can implement the accessory view delegate BUT you must remember to put a UIControl **or this method will not be called**. Otherwise that view needs to handle its own touch events. 
from the documentation:

> If the view you specify is also a descendant of the UIControl class,
>   you can use the map view’s delegate to receive notifications when your
>   control is tapped. If it does not descend from UIControl, your view is
>   responsible for handling any touch events within its bounds.

[reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView)